# Start conversation in Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

How can I achieve to start a conversation with Android Auto? Android Auto Help page says that to send a message the user has to say

> Message Cody White on Hangouts.

How can I add my application to this *Message on* command? Is it possible for any app?